# Space atop of align should depend on length of preceding line

Tags: spacing, align

[image: reality vs expectation]

If a short line is followed by an `align` environment then the spacing between the aligned content and the text above it is too large (in my opinion). See the spacing above `x = y_i` in the example. The standard display environment `\[ \]` seems to adjust this spacing depending on the length of the preceeding line, but `align` doesn’t seem to do this.

> Is there a way for `align` to make the space atop of it depend on the length of the preceeding line (like `\[ \]` does)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \texttt{align*}
    \end{center}
     text text text text text text text text text
    \begin{align*}
      x &= y_i
    \shortintertext{text}
      x &= z_{i+1}
    \end{align*}
    text text text text text text text text
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \texttt{\textbackslash[ \textbackslash]}
    \end{center}
    text text text text text text text text text
    \[
      x = y_i
    \]
    text
    \[
      x = z_{i+1}
    \]
    text text text text text text text text
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An `align` environment is a “full line equation”, so TeX always use `\abovedisplayskip` and not `\abovedisplayshortskip`.

Comment: @egreg, please, do you have an example for `\abovedisplayshortskip`?

Comment: You can, in cases when you find the spacing too large, add, just before the environment, `\useshortskip` (from `nccmath` – to be loaded before `mathtools`).)

Comment: Another option would be to use an `aligned` environment inside `equation*`.

Comment: But as was pointed out to me over in chat, that does not help if you want the parts to be numbererd. Or if only the first line is short (on the left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments and in the `mathtools` manual (section 3.1.5) this is a problem that some of the AMS environments have.
The `mathtools` package provides the command `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` to fix this problem manually.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \texttt{align*}
    \end{center}
     text text text text text text text text text
    \begin{align*}
      \SwapAboveDisplaySkip % less space
      x &= y_i
    \shortintertext{text}
      x &= z_{i+1}
    \end{align*}
    text text text text text text text text
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \texttt{\textbackslash[ \textbackslash]}
    \end{center}
    text text text text text text text text text
    \[
      x = y_i
    \]
    text
    \[
      x = z_{i+1}
    \]
    text text text text text text text text
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```